# Can I report if a question is marked as duplicate, but actually it is not?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122190/result-of-mysqli-query-is-false) is marked as a duplicate. But the questioner does not know that was the answer. So is the question marked as duplicate correct?

Also, if I feel that the marked flag for that question is wrong, can I report it somewhere?

Comment: I'm not a PHP dev but that duplicate seems accurate. Why doesn't the duplicate answer this issue with backticks, quotes and double-quotes? If anything you need to explain why the dupe isn't correct.

Comment: If you knew anything about string literals in mysql, you wouldn't have posted this; or wanting to gain rep from it.

Comment: @rene *"I'm not a PHP dev"* - No, but I am. See the comment above ^

Comment: @rene I'm also betting that since the OP posted their own answer based on [their comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122190/result-of-mysqli-query-is-false?noredirect=1#comment73323753_43122190), that they're seeking to have the question reopened so they can post their comment to an answer in order to gain rep from it; a very cheap shot if you ask me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you don't know how glad I am that you are a PHP dev ... \o/

Comment: @rene I did have a go at "C++" many years ago; I liked it. Turbo Pascal was fun also *lol* - But PHP stuck with me.

Comment: Do you feel the duplicate is wrong @siddiq? If so, please tell us why.

Comment: IMHO, this was all for personal rep gain and "after the fact". You also had your chance to post an answer.

Comment: I would assume good faith but ... meh ...let's not make more drama out of it then strictly needed.

Comment: @rene Agreed. I just need to set the record straight here.

Comment: Stack gave us the tools to close questions as duplicates when ones previously asked contained/address the same error. If you have a problem with how Stack works, then you will need to post another (meta) question and to question "them" and their "system".

Comment: The close IMO; was valid, end of story.

Answer (score 4):

In general it is OP's call whether duplicate question solves  they problem or not.

If you found case where duplicate is clearly wrong  - comment why you believe it is not duplicate, consider if editing post with that information  is appropriate (along with link to current duplicate) and vote/flag to re-open.

In this particular case I'd recommend no action as duplicate seem to be very appropriate and so far answers suggested in comment/posted as self-answer by OP looks low quality (and likely not the best practice for building SQL/MySQL queries).